# How to add new row with concatenated strings for each group?

Tags: r, dplyr

```
df <- tribble(~ID, ~Text,
              "Q1", "Never",
              "Q1", "Sometimes",
              "Q1", "Always",
              "Q2", "Agree",
              "Q2", "Disagree")
```

I tried using `add_row` and `paste`, but it obviously gives me an error. I also get a "Can't add rows to grouped data frames" error

```
df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  add_row(ID, paste(Text, sep = "; "))
```

I'm trying to get something like this:

| ID | Text |
| --- | --- |
| Q1 | Never |
| Q1 | Sometimes |
| Q1 | Always |
| Q1 | Never; Sometimes; Always |
| Q2 | Agree |
| Q2 | Disagree |
| Q2 | Agree; Disagree |

Comment: This should work: `df %>% group_by(ID) %>% group_modify(~add_row(.x, Text=paste(.x$Text, collapse = "; ")))`

Comment: Don't know why this question was closed with a non relevant link given in the closure.